# Getting only nulls using spark.readStream .format("s3-sqs") to get SQS messages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-sqs, databricks

I am trying to read messages from an Amazon SQS queue.  Permissions are working, I can see a record count - but all records are nulls.  Can't figure out why I am getting null values.  I can see the messages in the SQS queue and can get them from a local Python instance and they are in fact JSON records that reflect the schema (though not 100% sure that I have implemented the schema correctly).

Also using the "rate" format works all the way through the code.

Documentation is very sparse on this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val awsAccessKey = "blahblah"    
val awsSecretKey = "blahblahblahblah"
val awsRegion = "us-east-1"

val SQSQueue = "https://sqs.us-east1.amazonaws.com/blahblahblahblah/blahblahblahblah"

// SQS Event Structure
val sqsSchema = new StructType()
      .add(StructField("Records", ArrayType(new StructType()
      .add(StructField("eventVersion", StringType))
      .add(StructField("eventSource", StringType))
      .add(StructField("awsRegion", StringType))
      .add(StructField("eventTime", StringType))
      .add(StructField("eventName", StringType))
      .add(StructField("userIdentity",StringType))
      .add(StructField("eventName", StringType))
      .add("userIdentity", new StructType()
          .add(StructField("principalId", StringType)))
          .add("requestParameters", new StructType()
          .add(StructField("sourceIPAddress", StringType)))
     .add("responseElements", new StructType()
          .add(StructField("x-amz-request-id", StringType))
          .add(StructField("x-amz-id-2", StringType))
    )
.add("s3", new StructType()
    .add(StructField("s3SchemaVersion", StringType))
    .add(StructField("configurationId", StringType))
    .add("bucket",  new StructType()
      .add(StructField("name", StringType))
         .add("ownerIdentity", new StructType()
              .add(StructField("principalId", StringType)))
      .add(StructField("arn", StringType)))
    .add("object", new StructType()
         .add(StructField("key",StringType))
         .add(StructField("size", IntegerType))
         .add(StructField("eTag", StringType))
         .add(StructField("sequencer", StringType))
         )
     ))))

val df = spark.readStream
    .format("s3-sqs")
    //.format("rate") // this works
    .option("queueUrl", SQSQueue)
    .option("region",awsRegion)
    .option("awsAccessKey",awsAccessKey)
    .option("fileFormat", "json")
    .schema(sqsSchema)
    //.option("sqsFetchInterval", "1m")
    .load()

df.writeStream
      .queryName("sqs_records")    // this query name will be the table name
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("memory")
      .start()

val records = spark.sql("select * from sqs_records")

> records.count
    res142: Long = 4894

>%sql
    select * from sqs_records

Records
null
null
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, the schema you apply is the schema for your data and NOT the s3 event records sent to sqs.  You are getting null since the code is applying the s3 event schema to your data, which I'm sure doesn't match.

Comment: Late_answer that was indeed the problem.